# Consequences of changing a Motherboard and existing programs

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

Recently had a Gigabyte GA-X58-UD5 motherboard die on me. That particular board is no longer manufactured, and so far all attempts to find another have not been successful.  I had clone drives of my array and I'm signed up with carbonite; however, motherboard failure was a problem I never considered.

I have a lot of NLE software installed on this computer including lots of programs that were download only.  Since upgrading the motherboard looks like the only available option will these programs even work, or rather what would I have to do to get them to work?  I've had computer repair shops tell me I'm screwed, and others telling me I'm okay, but I need to know which before I shell out cash for another motherboard.

I was running Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/making-sure-windows-7-will-boot-after-changing-the-motherboard/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why you make regular image backups. ;)

Anyhow, changing just the motherboard shouldn't cause any problems with your installed software, as long as you can get the existing Windows install to boot.

If you get a similar board, with a similar drive controller, then it will probably boot without much hassle.

In regards to your installed software caring about the new board, it shouldn't -- the only exception to this is if any of your software uses the motherboard BIOB information (serial number, etc.) as a copy-protection lock.  Fortunately, these are rare.

Even if it's not going to preserve all your software, you should probably get the new motherboard anyway, unless you just don't want a computer anymore. :)